# Future/Completer could be called only once?

Tags: dart

Please consider the following code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

abstract class ClassAbstract
{
   Completer<String> _onEvent1;
   Completer<int> _onEvent2;

   ClassAbstract()
   {
     _onEvent1 = new Completer<String>();
     _onEvent2 = new Completer<int>();
   }

   Future get Event1
   {
      return _onEvent1.future; 
   }

   Future get Event2
   {
      return _onEvent2.future;
   }
}

class NormalClass extends ClassAbstract
{
   NormalClass(): super()
   {
     _onEvent1.complete("Event1 rise");
     for (int iCounter = 0; iCounter < 100; iCounter++)
     {
       _onEvent2.complete(iCounter);
     }
  }
}


void main() {

  NormalClass normalClass = new NormalClass();

  normalClass.Event1.then( (val) { print("Event1 rised"); } );
  normalClass.Event2.then( (val) { print("Event2 rised: $val"); } );

  print("Application close");
}
```

As you can see it's very simple code that has 1 `abstract` class with 2 `Futures` defined, getter for those 2 `Futures`. Another class that implement this `abstract` class and call the `Features` to simulate .NET events system.

The problem is whenever I run this code it fails with error in `for(int iCounter....)`  line with error: `Future already complete`.

Does it mean that I can `complete` Future only once ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's it. If you want to trigger several values you have to deal with [Stream](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Stream.html) and [StreamController](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamController.html). See [Introducing new Streams API](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/11/introducing-new-streams-api.html)  for more informations.

Comment: yes.. I already found this: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1873   and this: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/event_stream


BTW: Observable implementation of Events is *Amazing*

Answer (score 4):

That is correct. Futures are designed for one-use asynchronous calls. Basically a future can only provide one value. If you wish to provide multiple values then you will want to make use of a [Stream](http://api.dartlang.org/dart_async/Stream.html). Using a [StreamController](http://api.dartlang.org/dart_async/StreamController.html) you can easily add multiple values which can then be subscribed to.

So your sample would look like this:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

abstract class ClassAbstract
{
   StreamController<String> _onEvent1;
   StreamController<int> _onEvent2;

   ClassAbstract()
   {
     _onEvent1 = new StreamController<String>();
     _onEvent2 = new StreamContorller<int>();
   }

   Future get Event1
   {
      return _onEvent1.stream; 
   }

   Future get Event2
   {
      return _onEvent2.stream;
   }
}

class NormalClass extends ClassAbstract
{
   NormalClass(): super()
   {
     _onEvent1.add("Event1 rise");
     for (int iCounter = 0; iCounter < 100; iCounter++)
     {
       _onEvent2.add(iCounter);
     }
  }
}
```

and could be called something like this:

```dart
main() {
  var sum = 0;
  var thing = new NormalClass();
  thing.Event1.listen((myStr) => print(myStr));
  thing.Event2.listen((val) { 
    sum += val;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a Completer can only complete a Future once, which seems the most obvious to me. A Future is basically a token for an (read 'one') async operation. It will either succeed or fail.

What you are looking for in your case is an observer pattern where there is a source that dispatches events and listeners that will listen for events on the source. In this scenario, the source can dispatch the same event multiple times.

Edit: I was about to add some links to the Streams API, but Alexandre beat me to it. Check the [API docs](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Stream.html) for more info.

Comment: token ? it's 2 stage callback. Once you define it: completer.future and once you execute it: completer.complete()..... and that's it I guess. Too bad.. I thought it concept is very similar to 'event' but it's not - it just a callback.....

Comment: I refered to it as a token with regards to the client receiving the Future and registering a callback on it to handle the result and error. Similar to the AsyncToken class in the Flex framework: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/AsyncToken.html

Comment: Sorry.. don't know Flex... I have C# background